# More readable, DRY class with jira issue creation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jira

In my rails app I've got a base class - `creator` - which creates an issue in Jira board using [jira-ruby gem](https://github.com/sumoheavy/jira-ruby). I want to use it in 15 different scenarios but the only thing that will be different are required fields such as `summary`, `description`, and `issuetype`. To avoid duplicates I use inheritance where in each case I've got a class with only one method - `required_fields`.

`creator`

```
module Jira
  class Creator
    def initialize(webhook)
      @webhook = webhook
    end

    def call
      issue = client.Issue.build
      issue.save(ticket_class.new(webhook).required_fields)
    end

    private

    def client
      @client ||= Jira::JiraConnection.new.call
    end

    def ticket_class
      @ticket_class ||= "Issues::#{webhook.action_type_class}".constantize"
    end

    def required_fields; end
  end
end
```

Sample of class inheriting from Creator:

```
class NewRepo < Creator
  def required_fields
    {
      'fields' => {
        'summary' => 'Create new repo <github_repo> for <Github user>',
        'description' => 'This is an automatic confirmation of creating new PRIVATE repo
        - <github_repo> for <Github user>',
        'project' => { 'key' => 'TEST' },
        'issuetype' => { 'id' => '12580' },
        'customfield_15100' => 'None'
      }
    }
  end
end
```

This is `required_fields` is not so readable, how to create such an class where hash in `required_fields` will be look like:

```
{
  'fields' => {
    'summary' => new_repo,
    'project' => testing_project,
    'issuetype' => autoresolved,
    'customfield_15100' => 'None'
  }
}
```

How to put `new_repo`, `testing_project` etc (which will be a method probably?) inside of this hash? should I merge this somehow? Or maybe there is a better way to make this hash more readable?

Here are different scenarios for required fields which I want to use depends on webhook information:

```
class AddMember < Creator
  def required_fields
    {
      'fields' => {
        'summary' => 'Add <Github user> collaborator to <github_repo>',
        'description' => 'This is an automatic ticket confirmation of user added',
        'project' => { 'key' => 'New Board' },
        'issuetype' => { 'id' => '12581' },
        'customfield_15100' => 'None'
      }
    }
  end
end

class DeleteRepo < Creator
  def required_fields
    {
      'fields' => {
        'summary' => 'Recheck <Github user> deleted <github_repo>',
        'description' => 'This is an automatic ticket confirmation of delete repo <github_repo>',
        'project' => { 'key' => 'Second Board' },
        'issuetype' => { 'id' => '1234' },
        'customfield_15100' => 'None'
      }
    }
  end
end
```

Comment: I am not sure if I understand the question, but what about creating `@fields = {}` on your initialize, and then just have a method `add(property, value)` that does something like `@fields[property] = value`, so you can add all the fields that you want and then return `@fields` that will have all the fields that you added before

Comment: I don't understand your concept